# Xamarin forms how to display data on a listView(REST API)

Tags: c#

I'm new in xamarin cross platform development in visual studio.
I want to display a list of items on the listView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
         x:Class="Envelope_Internal.MainAssign">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>

</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ListView ItemsSource="{ Binding assignmentList }"
                   HasUnevenRows="True">

        </ListView>
```

```
namespace Envelope_Internal
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainAssign : ContentPage
    {
        DataService dataService;
        List<AssignListV> assignmentList;
        public MainAssign()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataService = new DataService();
            RefreshData();
        }



        async void RefreshData()
        {
            assignmentList = await dataService.GetAssignmentItemsAsync();
            assignmentList.item;
        }

    }
}

namespace Envelope_Internal
{
    public class DataService
    {
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public DataService()
        {
        }

        public async Task<List<AssignListV>> GetAssignmentItemsAsync()
        {

            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://munipoiapp.herokuapp.com/api/applications/New");
                var assignmentItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssignListV>>(response);
                return assignmentItems;
            }
            catch (System.Exception exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried this with a view model? I am not sure if it works without

Comment: Also you can try adding the `DataService` inside the constructor in a load event with async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing DataTemplate part in list and wrong using Binding.
From use Binding you can assing exemplar of ViewModel with BindingContext

```
   <ListView
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>



   public partial class MainAssign : ContentPage
        {

            public MainAssign()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                BindingContext = new MainAssignViewModel();
            }


            protected override async void OnAppearing() {
                base.OnAppearing();
                await (BindingContext as MainAssignViewModel)?.LoadData();
            }

        }

        public class MainAssignViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged {

            List<AssignListModel> _assignmentList;

            public MainAssignViewModel() {
                _dataService = new DataService();
            }
            public List<AssignListModel> AssignmentList {
                get { return _assignmentList; }
                set {
                    _assignmentList = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AssignmentList));
                }
            }

            readonly DataService _dataService;

            public async Task LoadData() {
                AssignmentList = await _dataService.GetAssignmentItemsAsync();
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

Comment: "indigentApplicationDetails": {"householdDetail": [
                {
                    "currentApplicationRefNo": "1000048609",
                    "personDetail": {
                        "gender": "Male",
                        "surname": "Motlhamme",}

Comment: I want to display currentApplicationRefNo and personal details

Comment: Replace Text="{Binding Name}" to Text="{Binding currentApplicationRefNo.householdDetail.currentApplicationRefNo}" in ViewCell

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link for showing data in a listview :
https://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.in/2017/04/xamarinforms-consuming-rest-webserivce_17.html

Comment: Hey just thought id give you, a thank you for the great blog so informative. and clear and concise instructions! Great work